# Solidify thickness doesn't correspond to specified scale when I animate the scale of the solid

Tags: solidify-modifier

When I try to animate the scale of the solid, solidify thickness doesn't correspond to specified scale:

[image]

Comment: Please insert images directly into the question with the button provided rather than just adding links to them. [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post). - In any case your image doesn't tell us anything without any context or details.

Comment: maybe you need to apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A)

Comment: If you scale the object non-uniformly, the thickness will scale non-uniformly. Do you want a somehow-defined even thickness, when the object is scaled by different amount in different directions?

Comment: @moonboots -- if this user wants to *animate* the scale, is there a way to apply the new scale at every frame as you suggest?

Comment: @james_t  I missed that   :/    he should apply the Solidify modifier

Comment: or instead of scaling in Object mode, use a shapekey to scale the object in Edit mode?

Comment: or armature deform!  (convenient, bones can scale in 3 dimensions just like an object, but it's still deformation not transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scaling in *Object* mode will vary the *Solidify* thickness. Instead of scaling in *Object* mode, you could use a shapekey to scale the object in *Edit* mode, the thickness will remain unchanged:

[image]